# What word is 咲かそう an inflection of?

Tags: words

I saw this word in a song. The lyrics read:

> 大きな花を**咲かそう**としてる

What word is it an inflection of? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「[咲]{さ}く」 ← Base verb.  "to bloom"

↓

「咲かす」 ← Causative form of 「咲く」.  "to let/make bloom"

↓

「咲かそう」 ← Volitional form of 「咲かす」.  "willing/about to let/make bloom"

Thus, 「大きな花を咲かそうとしてる」 would mean:

"trying to make big flowers bloom" or

"~~ is about to make big flowers bloom"

At least one of these would fit the context.  If neither one does, you will need to show more context.

Answer (score 1):

It's an inflection of

> 咲く

Besides, its causative verb form is,

> 咲かす

If you transform the word ending with おう to make it volitional verb,

> 咲かそう

Your lyric can read as :

> We are giving a try to bloom big flowers.

To add a knowledge,
It has its sibling which works almost the same

> 咲かせる

Both of them works as a causative verb.