# What is the meaning of 書く (書かそう) in this obscure conjugation?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

This is a quote I found from Kokoro Connect Ep. 1 @7:01

Context: Inaba asks Iori what types of material they should put in their school newspaper. Iori goes on to suggest they include explicit material. Inaba, who is very much against the idea, rejects the proposal due to the nature of content. 
Iori then says:

> たまにはそういうのもありだと思う…てなわけで稲葉ん今度はエロにも挑戦
> I think that sort thing is also okay once in a while. With that said, this time Inaba, you will try erotica as well.

Inaba replies with:

> 高１の純情な乙女にエロネタを**書かそうとするな**

The **書かそう** does seem to act like it's in a volitional form of sorts considering とする comes after it. However, I understand that the volitional form would be 書こう. In any case, any help would be much appreciated in understanding the meaning of this conjugation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28403/45489

Comment: @sundowner It does help a lot as a reference, although I thought the causative form for 書く is 書かせる. Is the volitional form that is used in 書かす derived from a particular dialect? Or is it merely a contraction?

Comment: It is an archaic causative form https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43474/45489